# pod install command unsuccessful. Returns ruby gems not installed

Tags: ruby, cocoapods

I have a react native project, and I'm running pod install in the iOS directory of the project, but I'm getting the an error about some gems that aren't found:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin20/rbconfig.rb:229: warning: Insecure world writable dir /Users/prikshetsharma/.rbenv/shims in PATH, mode 040777
Traceback (most recent call last):
    16: from /usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
    15: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `activate_bin_path'
    14: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:303:in `synchronize'
    13: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:304:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    12: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
    11: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
    10: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
     9: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     8: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
     7: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
     6: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
     5: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1452:in `block in activate_dependencies'
     4: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1420:in `activate'
     3: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `activate_dependencies'
     2: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1438:in `each'
     1: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1449:in `block in activate_dependencies'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:311:in `to_specs': Could not find 'minitest' (~> 5.1) among 69 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0:/usr/local/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.0/libexec', execute `gem env` for more information
```

How to fix this error?